# It is possible to get backend custom error message with d3.json?

Tags: django, d3.js, promise

I develop a django application where I have a d3js interactive tree. I use d3.json to get the tree data from the django view. I have create a decorator to check if user is logged to allowed the request or not. I have no problem when the user is logged but when the decorator return the jsonResponse with redirection url I have only the status error with the status description.

I read d3js and promise documentation but I'm not found a answer to return a jsonresponse with my custom response.

```
d3.json(d.data.url).then(function(data) {
          // process data no problem
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
```

```py
def check_user_permission_js(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        messages.warning(request,
            "Your account doesn't have access to this page "
            + "or your session has expired. "
            + "To proceed, please login with an account that has access.")
        return JsonResponse({'not_authenticated': True,
                             'redirect_url': settings.LOGIN_URL,'data':[]}, status=500)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is not specific to d3 or frontend code.

If you are using d3 v5, `d3.json` is a thin wrapper around the browser `fetch` API [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status), which seems to be correctly returning a non 200 status code. If the problem is that you're not getting the custom fields provided in `JsonResponse` to appear in the response returned to the frontend, then the issue is related to usage of the Django `JsonResponse` method, it isn't something that using a different data fetching library would change.

Answer (score 0):

I No I don't think the error comes from django because I already use JSONresponse with ajax requests that work very well. Exemple:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/browser/project/get-header",
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            // process my data
          },
          error: function(jqXHR){
            if (jqXHR.responseJSON.message){
              writeMessages(jqXHR.responseJSON.message, 'error');
            }
            else{
              writeMessages(
                'An error occur: the sample list can not be loaded!',
                'error');
            }
          }
        });
```

My problem is related to fetch and how d3js returns the error with d3.json.

To temporarily solve my problem I use requests like the one above but in the end I would like to use only the functions of D3JS.